# Are globs using `@()` more efficient than brace expansion?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to condense some globs and found that `@()` and brace expansion provide the same functionality. However, I'm curious if either is more efficient than the other.

For example, do either of these win out?

`./**/*.?(m|c){j,t}s` or `./**/*.?(m|c)@(j|t)s`

My assumption is that `@()` would preform better, because it wouldn't pole the data set multiple times. But, I don't really know.

Comment: Why not right some benchmark tests, run them, and see which is more efficient?

Comment: Why is this tagged nodejs?

Comment: Just the environment I'm working in. I imagine they work differently in Node.js than they do in bash.